# Draft.js modify text-alignment styles only on lists?

Tags: javascript, css, draftjs

When using Draft.js, I'm able to use `blockStyleFn` to modify the styling of list items by using `contentBlock.getType() === 'unordered-list-item'` which only targets the `li`. I'm not able to target the surrounding `ul` or `ol` though.

When using `textAlignment="center"`, it's causing some strange styling. I'd like to override this behavior by adding styles to the `ul` and `ol` tags as well as the `li`, but I'm not able to target the surrounding `ul` or `ol` using `blockStyleFn`.

Another issue is Draft.js adding HTML such as `div` and `span` tags in the `li`. Because of this, it's even harder to achieve my goal.

**How would i go about using `textAlignment="center"` but modify it just for lists?**